# Why is PHP is_link function returning FALSE?

Tags: php, filesystems

I created a shortcut on windows desktop to a file and used `is_link()` to check if it will be reported as a link. However, this function always seems to return FALSE. Am I misinterpreting something?

```
var_dump(is_link("score_shortcut.txt"));
```

Are windows shortcuts not considered symbolic link. Even if you downvote this question please point me to a right resource where I can read about it. Here is what I found about symbolic links and it looks like `score_shortcut.txt` should have returned TRUE.

> A symbolic link, also termed a soft link, is a special kind of file that points to another file, much like a shortcut in Windows or a Macintosh alias. Unlike a hard link, a symbolic link does not contain the data in the target file. It simply points to another entry somewhere in the file system.

Comment: A symbolic link is *like* a shortcut, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: A shortcut is an ordinary file, but the Windows GUI recognizes it as telling it to run another program. It has additional data like parameters that should be used when running the program.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Is there any symbolic link in Windows GUI which will return true for `is_link()`?

Comment: Use the `mklink` command https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I tried it but I kept getting the error "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." I am using different names. I even changed the directory. Do I also need to change the drive?

Comment: Nevermind. I swapped the links. Everything is working now. :)

Answer (score 2):

A symlink is a file system object but a Windows short-cut is just a regular file (more specifically, a file with `.lnk` extension) with data that Windows explorer uses to emulate links<sup>1</sup>. Thus `is_link()` is totally correct.

In practice, the difference stands out when you try to use the short-cut outside the context of Windows explorer: typing `dir foo` in a command-prompt is useless, you drag the short-cut into a program and it doesn't open... Such stuff.

*(<sup>1</sup>) The feature originated as a workaround to implement links in a file system that would not support it (namely FAT).*